# Box2d Libgdx how to make a realistic Car turn

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am having a rectangle which should represent a car. It should rotate when you tuch the display. How to make this with box2d. I already setted all up: Press W to accelerate and touch display for right turn and dont touch it for left turn. Problem is that the car is drifting when you rotate it and not immediately goes only to the direction its facing to. So far this is my code, how to remove this drifting, its like it drives on ice. :/

**EDIT:** (copied from C++ code: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car I tried to copy everything until the Torque so now It should drive. But when I do accelerate. It does not move. The currentSpeed Variable is 0 and the currentForwardNormal is 0.0 ,0.0. What did I wrong?)

```
//Main upate
public void update(float delta) {
    updateFriction();
}        

//Movements and Subclasses of them
public void accelerate() {
    //find current speed in forward direction
    Vector2 currentForwardNormal = ship.getWorldVector(new Vector2(0,1));
    float currentSpeed = getForwardVelocity().dot(currentForwardNormal);

    //apply necessary force
    float force = 0;
    if(maxSpeed > currentSpeed) {
        force = maxDriveForce;
    } else {
        force = -maxDriveForce;
    }
    System.out.println("Current Speed: "+currentSpeed);
    System.out.println("Current Forward Normal: "+currentForwardNormal);
    ship.applyForceToCenter(currentForwardNormal.scl(force),true);
}

public void rotate(boolean direction) { //true for Up and false for Down
    if(direction) {
        //torques
    }
}

private void updateFriction() {
    Vector2 impulse = getLateralVelocity().scl(-ship.getMass());
    ship.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, ship.getWorldCenter(), true);
    ship.applyAngularImpulse(0.1f * ship.getInertia() * -ship.getAngularVelocity(),true);
}

private Vector2 getLateralVelocity() {
    Vector2 currentRightNormal = ship.getWorldVector(new Vector2(1,0));
    return currentRightNormal.scl(currentRightNormal.dot(ship.getLinearVelocity()));
}

private Vector2 getForwardVelocity() {
    Vector2 currentRightNormal = ship.getWorldVector(new Vector2(0,1));
    return currentRightNormal.scl(currentRightNormal.dot(ship.getLinearVelocity()));
}
```

Comment: You need check if w and toch happened same time to do the turning, this behavior probably because the conditions excited at same time

Comment: as you can see above they are happening at the same time

Comment: yes,  so set condition to avoid the car go forward when touching. When w pressed it go forward same time toch pressed for turning. You need check if w and toch happened just turn the car and not go forward. You are doing the w separate and turning at same time,  so it's going forward and turning wich make it drift

Comment: For example if ( w and toch) {turn();}else if (w) forward();

Comment: Are you familiar with differentials and why cars need them to avoid skidding when turning? That said, I've never modeled this so I don't know if there is a trick to avoiding that complexity in Box2D.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with differential but if you know how move the car straight you can calculate the angle to make it turns too.  here is article to help you get through,  http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/

Comment: thanks for the tipps but they doesnt help fixing it.  @lvl4fi5 I dont understand what you are meaning :/ can you explain it better?

Comment: Have you looked at the [iforce2d's Top-down car physics tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car)? I'd recommend checking it out. I think it can answer at least some of what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for the Tipp its working ;)